# python add timestamp to console output

Tags: python, logging, time, console, timestamp

I would like to add a timestamp for each output in console.

My tool is using selenium and clicks on specific things on a website.
when specific events happen (for example see below code block) I would like to print it with a timestamp.

```
print(f'Bought player: {str_player_name} for {int_player_price}')
print(f'Estimated profit: {int_expected_profit}')
print(f'Player counter {str(int_players_bought)}/{str(int_max_players_bought)}')
```

I have many prints in my console - is there a way to automatically add a timestamp to each print('')?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `printf` function for that too

```
from datetime import datetime


def printf(*arg, **kwarg):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(timestamp, *arg, **kwarg)
```

Then, replace all your `print` call into `printf`.

---

But what you are trying to do is the job of the [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). I suggest you should add loggers to your code before it becomes complicated.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your code

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().strftime(%H:%M:%S))
```

Comment: hm would i have to add it once in my code? or everytime I print a message?

Comment: Everytime you print a message